# Не появляется окно electron после сборки

Tags: node.js, electron

Моя папка проекта выглядит вот так:

- app-name:

  - node_modules
  - renderer:

    - css:

      - scss:

        - main.scss
      - main.css
      - main.min.css
    - js:

      - main.js
    - index.html
  - app.js
  - icon.ico
  - package.json
  - package-lock.json

После сборки через electron-builder, у меня не появляется окно и в процессах пусто.
Скорее всего нужно как-то указать папку renderer в сборку, но я уже многое перепробовал и ничего не получается, буду очень рад помощи.
**[UPD]

Я распаковал app.asar и увидел, что в ней есть папка renderer, НО, в папке node_modules довольно мало папок, может в этом дело?**

[UPD]
Репозиторий: https://bitbucket.org/Oliver_Patterson/parser/src/master/

[UPD]
Решение проблемы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1236138/423297

---

Offtop: Не знаю, правильно ли я делаю, что пишу сюда..

И так.. После мучительных попыток, я выяснил вот что:
При создании экземпляра BrowserWindow, я указываю свойство icon, если я его убираю, после сборки проекта - все запускается.
Но вот не задача.. Я перепробовал указывать пути по разному и у меня ничего не получается.
Как поступать дальше?
Так же если использовать модуль "path" (const path = require('path')) в app.js, и использовать где-то в коде "path.join(..)", проект не запускается, даже ошибок нет.

Comment: Создайте проект с помощью [CLI](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/boilerplates-and-clis), используйте готовые `boilerplate`'ы если вы не можете создать собственный.

Comment: Я не очень хочу прибегать к использованию готовых шаблонов, хочется понять как самому с этим работать.

Comment: Я не вижу у вас в конфиге target. Если хотите чтобы кто-то вам реально помог, лучше дайте ссылку на репозиторий, чтобы можно было запустить ваш код. Это в ваших же интересах.

Comment: Я не делал репозиторий.

Comment: Создал и добавил ссылку на репозиторий.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не предоставили достаточно информации чтобы понять "почему". Посмотрите готовые конфигурации, просто чтобы понять как они работают. Скорее всего, найдете какой-то неучтенный параметр.
Пример темплейта: https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue

Доки quick start
https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder#quick-setup-guide
Там есть пример конфигурации. Мне кажется, стоит указать опции для платформы, для которой вы собираете приложение. Если вы сейчас на mac, то укажите для mac. Потому что по дефолту builder собирает asar архив, который не является исполнительным файлом.

```
"build": {
   "appId": "your.id",
   "mac": {
   "category": "your.app.category.type"
   }
}
```

Comment: Какая информация нужна?

Comment: Конфигурация ваша. По какой инструкции делали и тп.

Comment: Я оставил в первом посте свой package.json, я не знаю, что еще нужно. Я начал заниматься NodeJS буквально дня два-три назад.