# Не появляется окно electron после сборки, если для него указан icon

Tags: node.js, electron

При создании экземпляра BrowserWindow, если я указываю свойство icon, после сборки проекта не запускается .exe, если я убираю свойство - все запускается.

В чем может быть проблема?

[UPD]

```
function createWindow()
{
    mainWindows = new BrowserWindow(
    {
        height: 150,
        width: 300,
        resizable: 0,
        show: 0,
        autoHideMenuBar: 1,
        webPreferences:
        {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            enableRemoteModule: true
        },
        icon: './icon.ico',
        title: 'Parser by CZAR',
    });
}
```

Файл [icon.ico](https://bitbucket.org/Oliver_Patterson/parser/src/f2499d434d70856551c16c38a2b5c62fa414daba/icon.ico?at=master)

[UPD]

Репозиторий моего приложения: https://bitbucket.org/Oliver_Patterson/parser/src/master/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Файл](https://bitbucket.org/Oliver_Patterson/parser/src/master/icon.ico), который вы хотите использовать в качестве иконки

1. не является файлом формата `ico` - он `png`. изменение расширения файла не меняет его формат.
2. ваш файл `icon.ico`, который, как мы выяснили, формата `png`, содержит в себе ошибки, которые влияют на работу с ним. Electron падает именно из-за этих ошибок.

Чтобы ваше приложение запускалось, нужно исправить ошибки и расширение вашего файла.

Вот - [файл без ошибок](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5Vej.png). Скачайте. Переименуйте в `icon.png`. И вставьте в код:

```
new BrowserWindow({
  ...
  icon: './icon.png',
  ...
})
```

---

**UPD1**

> С этой иконкой тоже не запускается.

Так как автор вопрос не указал какие ошибки он видит в консоли, будем бить по площадям.

Загружаете новый [файл картинки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG9aQ.png). Эта версия отличается от предыдущей размером (512x512) и может быть использована как иконка приложения, а не окна приложения, как в вопросе.

После того как файл загружен, переименовываем его в `icon.png`.

В текущем коде `app.js` делаем такие изменения:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain: ipc } = require('electron');
...
const path = require('path');

function createWindow()
{
    const iconPath = path.join(
        app.isPackaged ? app.getAppPath() : process.cwd(),
        'icon.png'
    );

    mainWindows = new BrowserWindow({
        ...
        icon: iconPath,
        ...
    });
}
```

Запускаем сборку

```bsh
$ yarn compil
```

И у меня собранное приложение запускается.

Comment: По первому пункту, иконка конвертировалась еще давно через сайт из png to ico, я не знаю почему такое могло случиться. Насчет остального - спасибо, проверить смогу уже только завтра, тогда и дам оценку посту. Еще хотел бы спросить, я подключаю модуль (const path = require('path');) но после его использования ( path.join(...) ) Код дальше не выполняется, я пологаю, что там ошибка, но в консоли ничего нет. А так же, как указать иконку для сборки? Не очень это понял, извиняюсь, если нужно было для этих вопросов создать новую тему.

Comment: правильно модуль подключается не так `const { path } = require('path');` <- так в коде. напишите `const path = require('path');`. а падает всё из-за плохой картинки, сам `join`, в случае правильного написания, отрабатывал правильно

Comment: Я в скобочках и написал как я подключал. И как вообще получается, что код запускается с картинкой этой, а когда собираешь - нет? И как связан join с битой картинкой? Допустим я просто пытался вывести результат в консоль, работы данного метода.

Comment: у меня electron не запускал приложение с этой картинкой. простое несобранное приложение не запускал

Comment: Как мне ее можно указать для сборщика? Чтобы он ее использовал? (build в package)

Comment: С этой иконкой тоже не запускается.

Comment: дополнил ответ UPD1

Comment: Отлично, данный способ сработал, но у .exe файла иконка электрона, как это исправить?  


"Так как автор вопрос не указал какие ошибки он видит в консоли"
Т.к. программа не запускалась только в собранном виде, я не знаю как посмотреть ошибки в консоли.

Comment: Забыл добавить, что иконка теперь хранится "./assets/img/icon.png".