# Как правильно прописать путь до иконки приложения Electron Vue

Tags: vue.js, typescript, electron

Добавил иконку приложения

```
export const IconPath = join(__dirname, "..", "img", "icons", "win", "icon-logo.ico");

await win.setIcon(IconPath);
```

При запуске через IDE всё работает. Икона отображается.
Но после запуска `"electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build"`
После установки приложение работает, но иконка остаётся дефолтная электронской.

Если пытаешься установить через `icon: IconPath` то после билда приложение просто зависает. Хотя через IDE работает и иконку отображает корректно.

В чём может быть причина?

Comment: Думаю должен помочь оследний upd поста: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1236085/Не-появляется-окно-electron-после-сборки-если-для-него-указан-icon/1236138#1236138

Comment: @OliverPatterson Не помогло (((